# What is the matrix form of the definite integral from zero to infinity of the exponential of quadratic function

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral, gaussian

I've checked numerically that the definite integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left[-(ax^2+bx)\right]dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\exp\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)$$

has corresponding matrix form

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty...\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left[-(\mathbf x^T \mathbf A \mathbf x + \mathbf b^T \mathbf x)\right]dx_1dx_2...dx_N = \sqrt{\det\left(\pi\mathbf A^{-1}\right)}\exp\left(\frac{1}{4}\mathbf b^T \mathbf A^{-1} \mathbf b \right)$$

where $\mathbf x$ is an $N \times 1$ vector, $\mathbf A$ is a real symmetric $N \times N$ matrix, and $\mathbf b$ is an $N \times 1$ vector.

For the definite integral from $0$ to $\infty$

$$\int_{0}^\infty\exp\left[-(ax^2+bx)\right]dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\exp\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)\mathrm{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{4a}}\right)$$

where $\mathrm{erfc}$ is the complimentary error function. I've tried to guess the matrix form as

$$\int_{0}^\infty\int_{0}^\infty...\int_{0}^\infty\exp\left[-(\mathbf x^T \mathbf A \mathbf x + \mathbf b^T \mathbf x)\right]dx_1dx_2...dx_N$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\det\left(\pi\mathbf A^{-1}\right)}\exp\left(\frac{1}{4}\mathbf b^T \mathbf A^{-1} \mathbf b \right) \mathrm{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\mathbf b^T \mathbf A^{-1} \mathbf b}\right)$$

but it doesn't seem to work when I check with a numerical integration. I think I'm doing something wrong with the error function part of the expression. Does anyone know the solution? Thanks.

Comment: If you consider the case where $A$ is diagonal, you will see that the multiple integral decomposes into a product of integrals, so you will end up with the product of error functions. (Note that $\sqrt{\det(\pi A^{-1})}$ and $\exp(\frac{1}{4} b^\top A^{-1} b)$ will also arise as a product of individual terms.) For general [positive definite] $A$, I don't think there will be a clean expression.

Comment: $\mathbf A$ is a real symmetric matrix, so it is diagonalizable, but not necessarily diagonal.

Comment: I know, I'm just pointing out why your guess is incorrect by considering the special case of diagonal matrices. The last sentence of my comment expresses my belief that in the general case (for positive definite $A$) there won't be a simple expression for your integral.

Comment: I've tried using $\mathbf A = \mathbf O^T \mathbf D \mathbf O$ where $\mathbf D$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and $\mathbf O$ is an orthogonal matrix of eigenvectors. Then I can integrate with respect to $\mathbf y := \mathbf O \mathbf x$. I get this result
$\sqrt{\det\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbf A^{-1}\right)}\exp\left(\frac{1}{4}\mathbf b^T \mathbf A^{-1} \mathbf b \right) \prod_i \mathrm{erfc}\left(\frac{(\mathbf O \mathbf b)_i}{2\sqrt{\lambda_i}}\right)$, but it still seems to give the wrong answer compared to a numerical check.

Comment: Nevermind, I see what I'm doing wrong... I'm integrating over $0$ to $\infty$ in $\mathbf y$ as opposed to $\mathbf x$